# Как сделать иконки подсвечивающимися? Только рамка

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, svg

Сейчас на табах просто заменяю одну картинку другой картинкой при наведении и нажатии, но в `Safari` начинает мелькать. Подскажите другой способ, чтобы менялась не вся картинка, а только рамка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Через спрайты пробовал? Можно отрисовать эту картинку в свг, а в нем уже менять цвет заливки

Comment: добавьте ваш [mcve]

Comment: Еще как вариант можно методами JS скачать при загрузке страницы все файлы, которые меняются при наведении, и прописать события для элементов и заменять картинки

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Рамки проще всего сделать в SVG. Для этого используется атрибут - `stroke`.

Задавая `stroke` цвет - `fill` и ширину - `stroke-width`, легко добиться желаемого результата.
Идеально было бы, чтобы автор вопроса давал в вопросе код иконки.
У меня под рукой не нашлось шестиугольных иконок svg. Пришлось брать другие иконки и превращать их в шестиугольные.
Для этого я добавлял в код иконок шестиугольную рамку:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 110 110">
<polygon class="hex2" transform="scale(3.5) translate(-10 -21 )" 
points="24.8,22 37.3,29.2 37.3,43.7 24.8,50.9 12.3,43.7 12.3,29.2"  fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="#04AECF"   />  
</svg>
```

и соединял внутри одного файла рамку и найденную иконку:

```html
<style>
.hex2 {
stroke:#04AECF;
stroke-width:1;
fill:#3E4F71;

}

</style>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 110 110">
<polygon class="hex2" transform="scale(3.5) translate(-10 -21 )" 
points="24.8,22 37.3,29.2 37.3,43.7 24.8,50.9 12.3,43.7 12.3,29.2"    />  
<path fill="#EFEFEF" d="M47.985 68.99c-1.021 0-1.746-.787-1.995-.941-.797-.49-.603-.627-2.045-1.057l-4.038.01c-.503 0-.911-.404-.911-.902v-19.218c0-.499.408-.902.911-.902h5.342c.126-.068.518-.402 1.213-1.187 1.227-1.382 2.312-3.262 3.362-4.927.849-1.346 1.65-2.619 2.496-3.667 1.157-1.439 1.883-1.966 2.584-2.477.721-.522.574-.641 2.009-2.475 2.3-2.938 2.613-4.807 2.917-6.615.054-.32.109-.651.175-.981.259-1.307 1.405-2.659 2.876-2.658.53-.001 1.047.174 1.537.518 1.879 1.319 2.866 5.158 2.494 7.708-.383 2.619-1.578 6.005-2.681 7.23-.958 1.066-1.41 2.122-1.212 3.746.094.773 1.283.804 1.334.806l7.439.028c2.15.018 6.212.69 6.213 4.843 0 1.894-.77 3.071-1.666 3.757.852.758 1.516 1.742 1.278 3.609-.23 1.812-1.128 2.894-2.173 3.448.577.771.967 1.886.712 3.397-.245 1.455-1.134 2.469-2.048 2.961.431.658.699 1.666.473 2.869-.533 2.822-2.977 2.985-4.02 3.056l-.323.021h-22.253z"/><path fill="#DCDCDC" d="M76.34 49.629c.896-.686 1.666-1.863 1.666-3.757-.001-4.153-4.062-4.826-6.213-4.843l-7.439-.029c-.051-.002-1.24-.032-1.334-.806-.198-1.624.254-2.68 1.212-3.746 1.103-1.225 2.298-4.611 2.681-7.23.372-2.55-.615-6.389-2.494-7.708-.49-.344-1.007-.519-1.537-.518-.553 0-1.061.191-1.492.5l.029.018c1.879 1.319 2.866 5.158 2.494 7.708-.383 2.619-1.578 6.005-2.681 7.23-.958 1.066-1.41 2.122-1.212 3.746.094.773 1.283.804 1.334.806l7.439.028c2.15.018 6.212.69 6.213 4.843 0 1.894-.77 3.071-1.666 3.757.852.758 1.516 1.742 1.278 3.609-.23 1.812-1.128 2.894-2.173 3.448.577.771.967 1.886.712 3.397-.245 1.455-1.134 2.469-2.048 2.961.431.658.699 1.666.473 2.869-.533 2.822-2.977 2.985-4.02 3.056l-.323.021h3l.323-.021c1.043-.07 3.486-.233 4.02-3.056.227-1.203-.042-2.211-.473-2.869.914-.492 1.803-1.506 2.048-2.961.255-1.512-.135-2.627-.712-3.397 1.045-.555 1.942-1.636 2.173-3.448.237-1.866-.427-2.85-1.278-3.608zm-36.465 17.366l.032.007 1.059-.003-.021-.007-1.07.003zM76.34 49.629c.896-.686 1.666-1.863 1.666-3.757-.001-4.153-4.062-4.826-6.213-4.843l-7.439-.029c-.051-.002-1.24-.032-1.334-.806-.198-1.624.254-2.68 1.212-3.746 1.103-1.225 2.298-4.611 2.681-7.23.372-2.55-.615-6.389-2.494-7.708-.49-.344-1.007-.519-1.537-.518-.553 0-1.061.191-1.492.5l.029.018c1.879 1.319 2.866 5.158 2.494 7.708-.383 2.619-1.578 6.005-2.681 7.23-.958 1.066-1.41 2.122-1.212 3.746.094.773 1.283.804 1.334.806l7.439.028c2.15.018 6.212.69 6.213 4.843 0 1.894-.77 3.071-1.666 3.757.852.758 1.516 1.742 1.278 3.609-.23 1.812-1.128 2.894-2.173 3.448.577.771.967 1.886.712 3.397-.245 1.455-1.134 2.469-2.048 2.961.431.658.699 1.666.473 2.869-.533 2.822-2.977 2.985-4.02 3.056l-.323.021h3l.323-.021c1.043-.07 3.486-.233 4.02-3.056.227-1.203-.042-2.211-.473-2.869.914-.492 1.803-1.506 2.048-2.961.255-1.512-.135-2.627-.712-3.397 1.045-.555 1.942-1.636 2.173-3.448.237-1.866-.427-2.85-1.278-3.608zm-36.465 17.366l.032.007 1.059-.003-.021-.007-1.07.003z"/><path fill="#D7D7D7" d="M38.998 46.008h3.018v21h-3.018v-21z"/><path fill="#5879BD" d="M37.68 70.001h-11.067c-1.274 0-2.312-1.04-2.312-2.317l-3.304-21.38c0-1.279 1.037-2.318 2.311-2.318h14.372c1.275 0 2.312 1.039 2.312 2.318v21.38c-.001 1.277-1.038 2.317-2.312 2.317z"/><path fill="#fff" d="M33.993 61.006c1.105 0 2.001.895 2.001 1.999 0 1.103-.896 1.997-2.001 1.997s-2.002-.895-2.002-1.997c0-1.105.896-1.999 2.002-1.999z"/><path fill="#5170AE" d="M39.68 68.001h-11.067c-1.274 0-2.312-1.04-2.312-2.317l-3.304-21.38.029-.289c-1.141.141-2.029 1.107-2.029 2.289l3.304 21.38c0 1.277 1.037 2.317 2.312 2.317h11.067c1.176 0 2.139-.889 2.282-2.028l-.282.028z"/><path fill="#48639A" d="M33.993 65.002c-1.105 0-2.002-.895-2.002-1.997 0-.292.066-.568.179-.818-.694.313-1.179 1.008-1.179 1.818 0 1.103.896 1.997 2.002 1.997.813 0 1.51-.486 1.823-1.181-.252.114-.529.181-.823.181z"/></svg>
```

Осталось добавить подобные иконки и стили, которые меняют толщину и цвет рамок иконок при наведении:

```css
 svg path {
    pointer-events:none;
  }
.hex2 {
stroke:#04AECF;
stroke-width:0.5;
fill:#3E4F71;
transition:stroke-width .5s ease, stroke .5s;
}
.hex2:hover {
stroke:#2BCDD6;
stroke-width:2;

}
.container {
float:left;
margin: 40px 25px;

}
.main {
width:800px;
height:200px;
background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5xCL.png);
background-size:cover;
background-color:#5798B8;
}
```

```html
<div class="main" >
<div class="container"> 
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
<polygon class="hex2" transform="scale(3.3) translate(-10 -21.5 )" 
points="24.8,22 37.3,29.2 37.3,43.7 24.8,50.9 12.3,43.7 12.3,29.2"    />  

<path fill="#E2574C" d="M35.013 97.707c3.207 1.008 6.551 1.701 10 2.043v-99.501c-3.449.343-6.793 1.036-10 2.043v95.415z"/>
<path fill="#E4E7E7" d="M55.014.249c-1.645-.163-3.312-.25-5-.25-1.688 0-3.355.086-5 .25v99.501c1.645.164 3.312.25 5 .25 1.688 0 3.356-.086 5-.25v-99.501z"/>
<path fill="#324D5B" d="M55.014.256v99.487c3.447-.343 6.795-1.028 10-2.036v-95.415c-3.205-1.007-6.553-1.692-10-2.036z"/><path fill="#F5F5F5" d="M77.014 49.998c0-7.501-3.061-14.285-8-19.179v-6.819c0-1.133-.93-2.001-2-2.001h-1c-.553 0-1 .448-1 1v4.55c-4.291-2.873-9.449-4.55-15-4.55s-10.709 1.677-15 4.55v-4.55c0-.552-.448-1-1-1h-1c-1.071 0-2 .868-2 2.001v6.819c-4.939 4.894-8 11.678-8 19.179 0 7.502 3.061 14.287 8 19.18v6.821c0 1.179.921 1.999 2 1.999h1c.552 0 1-.447 1-1v-4.549c4.291 2.872 9.449 4.549 15 4.549s10.709-1.677 15-4.549v4.549c0 .553.447 1 1 1h1c1.078 0 2-.82 2-1.999v-6.821c4.939-4.893 8-11.678 8-19.18z"/><path fill="#CCD0D2" d="M50.013 27c12.704 0 23 10.297 23 23s-10.296 23-23 23c-12.703 0-23-10.299-23-23.001s10.298-22.999 23-22.999z"/><path fill="#DE6E65" d="M54.309 44.275l-15.987 15.989c-.394.393-.394 1.033 0 1.428.395.393 1.033.393 1.428 0l15.987-15.987c.395-.394.395-1.033 0-1.429-.395-.393-1.034-.393-1.428-.001z"/><path fill="#AEB2B4" d="M50.01 54.008c-2.212 0-4.004-1.791-4.004-4.003 0-.851.269-1.636.722-2.284-1.039.724-1.722 1.923-1.722 3.284 0 2.212 1.792 4.003 4.004 4.003 1.361 0 2.56-.683 3.283-1.721-.648.452-1.434.721-2.283.721z"/><path fill="#324D5B" d="M50.013 49h16c.553 0 1 .447 1 .999s-.447 1-1 1h-16c-.553 0-1-.448-1-1s.447-.999 1-.999zM43.199 40.538l8.247 8.247c.73.73.73 1.916 0 2.646s-1.916.73-2.646 0l-8.247-8.248c-.731-.73-.731-1.916 0-2.646.73-.73 1.914-.73 2.646.001z"/><path fill="#E4E7E7" d="M50.01 46c2.21 0 4.003 1.793 4.003 4.005s-1.793 4.003-4.003 4.003c-2.212 0-4.004-1.791-4.004-4.003s1.792-4.005 4.004-4.005z"/><path fill="#324D5B" d="M50.013 48c1.104 0 2 .895 2 1.999 0 1.105-.896 2.001-2 2.001s-2-.896-2-2.001c0-1.104.896-1.999 2-1.999z"/><path fill="#D96860" d="M46.568 52.018l-1 1c.347.592.836 1.081 1.427 1.428l1-1c-.591-.347-1.08-.837-1.427-1.428z"/><path fill="#B7BBBD" d="M50.013 27c-6.605 0-12.557 2.789-16.751 7.249 4.115-3.873 9.655-6.249 15.751-6.249 12.704 0 23 10.297 23 23 0 6.097-2.377 11.636-6.25 15.753 4.461-4.195 7.25-10.147 7.25-16.753.001-12.703-10.296-23-23-23z"/></svg>
</div> 
<div class="container"> 
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 110 110">
<polygon class="hex2" transform="scale(3.5) translate(-10 -21 )" 
points="24.8,22 37.3,29.2 37.3,43.7 24.8,50.9 12.3,43.7 12.3,29.2"    />  
<path fill="#37A18E" d="M79.222 72.675c-1.415-1.415-3.45-1.802-5.225-1.199l-4.722-4.723c3.365-4.424 5.367-9.942 5.367-15.931 0-14.546-11.792-26.338-26.339-26.338-14.546 0-26.338 11.792-26.338 26.338 0 14.547 11.792 26.339 26.338 26.339 5.988 0 11.507-2.002 15.931-5.368l4.723 4.723c-.602 1.773-.215 3.81 1.199 5.224l8.923 8.923c3.492-2.502 6.655-5.435 9.396-8.733l-9.253-9.255z"/>
<path fill="#F5F5F5" d="M68.535 63.464l-5.07 5.071 19.255 19.255c1.809-1.567 3.503-3.263 5.071-5.071l-19.256-19.255z"/>
<path fill="#fff" d="M48.5 22c14.636 0 26.5 11.864 26.5 26.5 0 14.635-11.864 26.5-26.5 26.5s-26.5-11.865-26.5-26.5c0-14.636 11.864-26.5 26.5-26.5z"/>
<path fill="#82CEE8" d="M48.5 27c11.874 0 21.5 9.626 21.5 21.5s-9.626 21.5-21.5 21.5-21.5-9.626-21.5-21.5 9.626-21.5 21.5-21.5z"/>
<path fill="#A8DDEF" d="M38.189 53.379c-.499-.5-1.31-.5-1.81 0s-.5 1.311 0 1.811l5.431 5.43c.5.5 1.31.5 1.81 0 .5-.499.5-1.31 0-1.81l-5.431-5.431zm11.435 4.45l-10.454-10.454c-.495-.495-1.299-.495-1.794 0s-.495 1.299 0 1.794l10.454 10.454c.495.495 1.299.495 1.794 0s.495-1.298 0-1.794z"/>
<path fill="#EFC75E" d="M79.606 70.485c-1.996-1.996-5.232-1.996-7.229 0l-1.892 1.892c-1.996 1.997-1.996 5.233 0 7.229l10.007 10.007c3.419-2.636 6.485-5.702 9.121-9.121l-10.007-10.007z"/>
<path fill="#D7B354" d="M72.507 77.606c-1.993-1.993-1.995-5.223-.008-7.22l-.121.099-1.892 1.892c-1.996 1.997-1.996 5.233 0 7.229l10.007 10.007c.755-.582 1.491-1.187 2.211-1.81l-10.197-10.197z"/>
<path fill="#72B5CC" d="M48.5 27c-6.701 0-12.684 3.067-16.627 7.873 3.71-3.044 8.454-4.873 13.627-4.873 11.874 0 21.5 9.626 21.5 21.5 0 5.173-1.829 9.917-4.873 13.627 4.806-3.943 7.873-9.926 7.873-16.627 0-11.874-9.626-21.5-21.5-21.5z"/>
</div>
<div class="container"> 
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 110 110">
<polygon class="hex2" transform="scale(3.5) translate(-10.5 -21.5 )" 
points="24.8,22 37.3,29.2 37.3,43.7 24.8,50.9 12.3,43.7 12.3,29.2"    />  

<path fill="#E2574C" d="1M35.013 97.707c3.207 1.008 6.551 1.701 10 2.043v-99.501c-3.449.343-6.793 1.036-10 2.043v95.415z"/>
<path fill="#E4E7E7" d="1M55.014.249c-1.645-.163-3.312-.25-5-.25-1.688 0-3.355.086-5 .25v99.501c1.645.164 3.312.25 5 .25 1.688 0 3.356-.086 5-.25v-99.501z"/>
<path fill="#324D5B" d="1M55.014.256v99.487c3.447-.343 6.795-1.028 10-2.036v-95.415c-3.205-1.007-6.553-1.692-10-2.036z"/><path fill="#F5F5F5" d="M77.014 49.998c0-7.501-3.061-14.285-8-19.179v-6.819c0-1.133-.93-2.001-2-2.001h-1c-.553 0-1 .448-1 1v4.55c-4.291-2.873-9.449-4.55-15-4.55s-10.709 1.677-15 4.55v-4.55c0-.552-.448-1-1-1h-1c-1.071 0-2 .868-2 2.001v6.819c-4.939 4.894-8 11.678-8 19.179 0 7.502 3.061 14.287 8 19.18v6.821c0 1.179.921 1.999 2 1.999h1c.552 0 1-.447 1-1v-4.549c4.291 2.872 9.449 4.549 15 4.549s10.709-1.677 15-4.549v4.549c0 .553.447 1 1 1h1c1.078 0 2-.82 2-1.999v-6.821c4.939-4.893 8-11.678 8-19.18z"/><path fill="#CCD0D2" d="M50.013 27c12.704 0 23 10.297 23 23s-10.296 23-23 23c-12.703 0-23-10.299-23-23.001s10.298-22.999 23-22.999z"/><path fill="#DE6E65" d="M54.309 44.275l-15.987 15.989c-.394.393-.394 1.033 0 1.428.395.393 1.033.393 1.428 0l15.987-15.987c.395-.394.395-1.033 0-1.429-.395-.393-1.034-.393-1.428-.001z"/><path fill="#AEB2B4" d="M50.01 54.008c-2.212 0-4.004-1.791-4.004-4.003 0-.851.269-1.636.722-2.284-1.039.724-1.722 1.923-1.722 3.284 0 2.212 1.792 4.003 4.004 4.003 1.361 0 2.56-.683 3.283-1.721-.648.452-1.434.721-2.283.721z"/><path fill="#324D5B" d="M50.013 49h16c.553 0 1 .447 1 .999s-.447 1-1 1h-16c-.553 0-1-.448-1-1s.447-.999 1-.999zM43.199 40.538l8.247 8.247c.73.73.73 1.916 0 2.646s-1.916.73-2.646 0l-8.247-8.248c-.731-.73-.731-1.916 0-2.646.73-.73 1.914-.73 2.646.001z"/><path fill="#E4E7E7" d="M50.01 46c2.21 0 4.003 1.793 4.003 4.005s-1.793 4.003-4.003 4.003c-2.212 0-4.004-1.791-4.004-4.003s1.792-4.005 4.004-4.005z"/><path fill="#324D5B" d="M50.013 48c1.104 0 2 .895 2 1.999 0 1.105-.896 2.001-2 2.001s-2-.896-2-2.001c0-1.104.896-1.999 2-1.999z"/><path fill="#D96860" d="M46.568 52.018l-1 1c.347.592.836 1.081 1.427 1.428l1-1c-.591-.347-1.08-.837-1.427-1.428z"/><path fill="#B7BBBD" d="M50.013 27c-6.605 0-12.557 2.789-16.751 7.249 4.115-3.873 9.655-6.249 15.751-6.249 12.704 0 23 10.297 23 23 0 6.097-2.377 11.636-6.25 15.753 4.461-4.195 7.25-10.147 7.25-16.753.001-12.703-10.296-23-23-23z"/></svg>
</div>
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 110 110">
<polygon class="hex2" transform="scale(3.5) translate(-10 -21 )" 
points="24.8,22 37.3,29.2 37.3,43.7 24.8,50.9 12.3,43.7 12.3,29.2"    />  
<path fill="#EFEFEF" d="M47.985 68.99c-1.021 0-1.746-.787-1.995-.941-.797-.49-.603-.627-2.045-1.057l-4.038.01c-.503 0-.911-.404-.911-.902v-19.218c0-.499.408-.902.911-.902h5.342c.126-.068.518-.402 1.213-1.187 1.227-1.382 2.312-3.262 3.362-4.927.849-1.346 1.65-2.619 2.496-3.667 1.157-1.439 1.883-1.966 2.584-2.477.721-.522.574-.641 2.009-2.475 2.3-2.938 2.613-4.807 2.917-6.615.054-.32.109-.651.175-.981.259-1.307 1.405-2.659 2.876-2.658.53-.001 1.047.174 1.537.518 1.879 1.319 2.866 5.158 2.494 7.708-.383 2.619-1.578 6.005-2.681 7.23-.958 1.066-1.41 2.122-1.212 3.746.094.773 1.283.804 1.334.806l7.439.028c2.15.018 6.212.69 6.213 4.843 0 1.894-.77 3.071-1.666 3.757.852.758 1.516 1.742 1.278 3.609-.23 1.812-1.128 2.894-2.173 3.448.577.771.967 1.886.712 3.397-.245 1.455-1.134 2.469-2.048 2.961.431.658.699 1.666.473 2.869-.533 2.822-2.977 2.985-4.02 3.056l-.323.021h-22.253z"/><path fill="#DCDCDC" d="M76.34 49.629c.896-.686 1.666-1.863 1.666-3.757-.001-4.153-4.062-4.826-6.213-4.843l-7.439-.029c-.051-.002-1.24-.032-1.334-.806-.198-1.624.254-2.68 1.212-3.746 1.103-1.225 2.298-4.611 2.681-7.23.372-2.55-.615-6.389-2.494-7.708-.49-.344-1.007-.519-1.537-.518-.553 0-1.061.191-1.492.5l.029.018c1.879 1.319 2.866 5.158 2.494 7.708-.383 2.619-1.578 6.005-2.681 7.23-.958 1.066-1.41 2.122-1.212 3.746.094.773 1.283.804 1.334.806l7.439.028c2.15.018 6.212.69 6.213 4.843 0 1.894-.77 3.071-1.666 3.757.852.758 1.516 1.742 1.278 3.609-.23 1.812-1.128 2.894-2.173 3.448.577.771.967 1.886.712 3.397-.245 1.455-1.134 2.469-2.048 2.961.431.658.699 1.666.473 2.869-.533 2.822-2.977 2.985-4.02 3.056l-.323.021h3l.323-.021c1.043-.07 3.486-.233 4.02-3.056.227-1.203-.042-2.211-.473-2.869.914-.492 1.803-1.506 2.048-2.961.255-1.512-.135-2.627-.712-3.397 1.045-.555 1.942-1.636 2.173-3.448.237-1.866-.427-2.85-1.278-3.608zm-36.465 17.366l.032.007 1.059-.003-.021-.007-1.07.003zM76.34 49.629c.896-.686 1.666-1.863 1.666-3.757-.001-4.153-4.062-4.826-6.213-4.843l-7.439-.029c-.051-.002-1.24-.032-1.334-.806-.198-1.624.254-2.68 1.212-3.746 1.103-1.225 2.298-4.611 2.681-7.23.372-2.55-.615-6.389-2.494-7.708-.49-.344-1.007-.519-1.537-.518-.553 0-1.061.191-1.492.5l.029.018c1.879 1.319 2.866 5.158 2.494 7.708-.383 2.619-1.578 6.005-2.681 7.23-.958 1.066-1.41 2.122-1.212 3.746.094.773 1.283.804 1.334.806l7.439.028c2.15.018 6.212.69 6.213 4.843 0 1.894-.77 3.071-1.666 3.757.852.758 1.516 1.742 1.278 3.609-.23 1.812-1.128 2.894-2.173 3.448.577.771.967 1.886.712 3.397-.245 1.455-1.134 2.469-2.048 2.961.431.658.699 1.666.473 2.869-.533 2.822-2.977 2.985-4.02 3.056l-.323.021h3l.323-.021c1.043-.07 3.486-.233 4.02-3.056.227-1.203-.042-2.211-.473-2.869.914-.492 1.803-1.506 2.048-2.961.255-1.512-.135-2.627-.712-3.397 1.045-.555 1.942-1.636 2.173-3.448.237-1.866-.427-2.85-1.278-3.608zm-36.465 17.366l.032.007 1.059-.003-.021-.007-1.07.003z"/><path fill="#D7D7D7" d="M38.998 46.008h3.018v21h-3.018v-21z"/><path fill="#5879BD" d="M37.68 70.001h-11.067c-1.274 0-2.312-1.04-2.312-2.317l-3.304-21.38c0-1.279 1.037-2.318 2.311-2.318h14.372c1.275 0 2.312 1.039 2.312 2.318v21.38c-.001 1.277-1.038 2.317-2.312 2.317z"/><path fill="#fff" d="M33.993 61.006c1.105 0 2.001.895 2.001 1.999 0 1.103-.896 1.997-2.001 1.997s-2.002-.895-2.002-1.997c0-1.105.896-1.999 2.002-1.999z"/><path fill="#5170AE" d="M39.68 68.001h-11.067c-1.274 0-2.312-1.04-2.312-2.317l-3.304-21.38.029-.289c-1.141.141-2.029 1.107-2.029 2.289l3.304 21.38c0 1.277 1.037 2.317 2.312 2.317h11.067c1.176 0 2.139-.889 2.282-2.028l-.282.028z"/><path fill="#48639A" d="M33.993 65.002c-1.105 0-2.002-.895-2.002-1.997 0-.292.066-.568.179-.818-.694.313-1.179 1.008-1.179 1.818 0 1.103.896 1.997 2.002 1.997.813 0 1.51-.486 1.823-1.181-.252.114-.529.181-.823.181z"/></svg>

</div>  
</div>
```

### Update

*доработка по замечаниям в комментариях*

Дефект заключался в несрабатывании `:hover` на некоторых деталях рисунка внутри иконки.
Причина понятна, так как рисунок расположен выше фона иконки, поэтому экранирует срабатывание `:hover` на фоне, который расположен ниже.  Решение простое,- добавить всем патчам рисунка свойство `pointer-events:none;` То есть сделать их прозрачными для событий курсора.

```
svg path {
    pointer-events:none;
  }
```

Comment: При наведении на иконку не срабатывает увеличение рамки

Comment: @St1myL срабатывает, но не на всех местах внутри кнопки, наверное надо всё обернуть в групповой тег и поставить pointer-events="none", чтобы насквозь пробивало

Comment: да именно это имел ввиду, но решение все равно хорошее (+)

Comment: не за что, обычно я беру ваши решения на вооружение))

Comment: имел ввиду плюс вам